# What are <<< and < <() used for in Bash?

Tags: bash, while-loop

I'm studying bash but I'm not able to understand this example code:

```
while IFS= read -r line2; 
    do
        if [[ "$line1" == "$line2" ]]
        then
            (( i++ ))
        fi
    done <<< "$lines"
```

in particular the line `done <<< "$lines"` what do mean `<<<`?

I find other example for example this:

```
while read line
  do
      echo "Word count per line: $line"
  done < <(cat list.txt | wc -w)
```

in this case because it uses `< <` and not `<<<`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you write a loop, you can feed it with the content of a file with the expression:

```
while ...; do
   # things
done < file
```

Then, you can take advantage of this by using a [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) instead of a file itself. This way, you can feed a `while` loop with the result of a process without having to pipe. Internally, it kind of creates a temporary file:

```
while ...; do
   # things
done < <(find -type f -name ".htaccess")
```

But, why is it important to use this approach instead of `cat file | wc -w | while ...`? Because this one will open a sub-shell, so that whatever variables you set within the `while` loop will be lost once it finishes.

For example, if you say:

```
$ var=5
$ seq 10 | while read v; do var=$v; done
```

Then the variable `$var` is not set to `10` at the end of the loop, but it remains unchanged:

```
$ echo $var
5
```

You can read more about it in [I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

---

Then, you have:

```
while ...; do
   # things
done <<< "$variable"
```

This feeds the `while` loop with a [here string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings). That is, the `while` loop keeps reading from the content of `$variable` until it is done.

For example, the following code:

```
while IFS=: read -r product price; do
   echo "$product cost $price euros"
done <<< "potatos:23
kiwis:45"
```

Will return:

```
potatos cost 23 euros
kiwis cost 45 euros
```

Answer (score 5):

`<<<` specifies a **[here string](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html)**.

In your case, the content of `$lines` is sent to the standard input of the `while` loop.

---

`<(...)` is a kind of **[process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)**.

In your case, the output of `cat list.txt | wc -w` is sent to the standard input of the `while` loop.

Process substitution is very useful when a program expects a file name as an argument.

Comment: not entirely equivalent: `cat file | ...` will open a subshell, so that the variables you set within the `while` loop will be lost after it is done.

Comment: @fedorqui: in this case it is perfectly equivalent

Comment: Yep, but it is good to mention there are differences between both approaches, not to fall in the problem [I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: @fedorqui: OK, I see what you mean. Re-reading my answer, the statement is ambiguous, I'd better remove it.

Comment: I edited your post to provide links to gnu.org/.../bash instead of tldp.org. Apparently, info there is not that reliable. Also, I don't really understand your sentence _Process substitution is very useful when a program expects a file name as an argument_ This is true, yes, but it is useful in way more number of cases : )

Comment: @fedorqui: it's just a short hint that I thought I could share. I don't see anything wrong with giving hints :)

Comment: @fedorqui: it is providing a filename for I/O redirection (`< /dev/fd/...`), actually

Comment: By the way, I see now that tldp provides helpful examples, while the Bash documentation does not.